# Children's book about a computer and a bat that could teleport the users anywhere

Tags: story-identification

I remember this being the first taste of *sci-fi* I ever had when I was a little kid, I think I was so young it was actually read to me, so it was probably available in the early 90's.

I remember it being largely picture based (to be expected for a kids book). I recall something to do with one of the locations that the characters were teleported to being a zoo. There were two main characters one of which was a bat, who was simply called "Bat". I also remember him being irrationally terrified of everything.

Would love to be able to figure this out and get a copy to read to my kids one day. Sorry it's not a lot to go on.